# Is it possible to get hwnd within Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my WebExtensions add-on, I need to get hwnd for browser window.

I can think of a way to do it, by send a query message to native messaging app, in native app, use `FindWindow()` to get browser hwnd, then send back to add-on.

I wonder, can I get hwnd in pure JavaScript (Without native messaging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No (after Firefox 57):  Use [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging)

No. What you have described (using native messaging) is the only way which will be available as of Firefox 57.

### Until Firefox 57, it's possible using a [WebExtensions experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

The [hwnd is exposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Finding_Window_Handles) to other types of Firefox add-ons. Thus, you could create a [WebExtensions experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to give you access to the hwnd in a WebExtensions based add-on. However, unless you can make a good case for it, I doubt that it is something that will be incorporated into stock Firefox.